# nginx - redirect all backlinks posted as category.domain.com/article to domain.com/category/article

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am just hobby blogger and as advised looked for answer before posting question here so please don't be harsh on me if the answer is quite obvious for you..I have tried few solutions offered here but nothing works for me..

Am in process of migrating all of my websites from debian/apache to ubuntu 14.04 LTS with nginx. I host multiple domains on same server. But for one of my website I used wordpress plugin called "category as subdomain" using wildcard subdomains so my website categories links looks like **category.domain.com/article**

The problem is I dont want it like that anymore because I learned that is just bad SEO practice. I want to switch to domain.com/category/article

On the website alone that is not a problem. It's just matter of disabling plugin. Problem are incoming links coming from various websites. I want redirect all traffic coming from **category.domain.com/requested-article** to **domain.com/category/requested-article** 
I have something like 10 categorys and many broken links from category subdomains..

This is the most logical answer I found here but yet without success:

```
server {
server_name ~^(?<sub>aaa|bbb|ccc)\.example\.com$; 
return 301 http://example.com/$sub$request_uri;
}
```

What am doing wrong? How to do this in correct way?

Comment: And you have a separate `server` block with `server_name example.com;`?

Comment: yes I have server block with example.com

Comment: You are missing a `~`: Use: `server_name ~^(?<sub>aaa|bbb|ccc)\.example\.com$;`

Comment: added ~ but still not working..when try to access from old link browser respond with - This webpage is not available

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: That's a DNS lookup problem. Make sure you typed in the domain name correctly in your `return` statement, and that `category.example.com` and `example.com` both have A records pointing to your server.